# The searchSuggestions method returns no albums

Tags: oauth, scope, rdio

I need to find albums using the "Mozart" query.
When I use Rdio API Console. it [returns](http://rdioconsole.appspot.com/#query%3DMozart%26types%3DAlbum%26method%3DsearchSuggestions) several albums. But in case of the curl utility, it returns nothing.

```
{"status": "ok", "result": []}
```

For searching I use the following command:

```
curl -X POST 'https://services.rdio.com/api/1/?method=searchSuggestions&types=Album&query=Mozart' -H 'Authorization: Bearer AAAAAWEAAAAAAhkPNgAAAABV1duTVdaEUwAAABpuaWlyZXR0eXZiZG1uZjdjbzJhNWxieHdkddStjPwN8G3shj01cryrkCYZT3pq429kU8cRqbPP85Ad'
```

Why this happens?

Maybe I need to specify the scope parameter while requesting OAuth 2.0 access token?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters must be passed in the body of the request, not in the query string. So the command should be:

```
curl -X POST 'https://services.rdio.com/api/1/' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCES_TOKEN' \
    -d 'method=searchSuggestions&types=Album&query=Mozart'
```

Comment: The result is the same as above.
    {"status": "ok", "result": []}

Comment: Make sure you're making the call as an authenticated user. http://www.rdio.com/developers/docs/guides/regions/